# How to properly Get first word of every sentence and push the values into array via php

Tags: php

This script works fine by getting the values of each first word in a sentence Eg.(Ann and Mike).  My issue is that the output of an array is not what I want.

I was expecting `$result_names = array("Ann","Mike");`  but I got

```
Array ( [0] => Ann [1] => Ann Mike )
```

**Here is the Code**

```
$names = array();

$str = 'Ann is good,"Mike loves cooking"';
$result = explode(',',$str); //parsing with , as delimiter 
$op = "";
foreach($result as $value)
{
    $tmp = explode(' ',$value);
    $op .= trim($tmp[0],"'\"")." ";

 $names[] = $op;

}
$op = rtrim($op);
$rr = ucwords($op);


print_r($names);
```

Comment: Just a typo...remove the `.=` and replace with `=`. Demo: https://3v4l.org/o2BcN

Comment: @ADyson . Thanks for getting back to me. Your answer works correct.  My final question. I need to check if certain name is in the array with the **$names** result something like `$name_search ='Ann';
$result_names = array("Ann","Mike");
if (!in_array($name_search, $result_names)) { 
echo "echo Name not Found";

}else{
echo "echo Name Found ";

}`   I have tried this but it keep saying Name not found  `$result_names = $names;
$name_search ='Ann';
if (!in_array($name_search, $result_names)) { 
echo "Name not Found";

}else{
echo "Name Found ";

}`

Comment: You added a space to the end of the strings in `$names`, with the `." "` code. So `Ann ` obviously isn't the same as `Ann` and so in_array_ fails. Remove that and it works: https://3v4l.org/BsPoF . It's unclear why you added the space character on purpose.

Comment: No worries. The problem seems to be largely the result of careless typos and/or not checking your code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code concatenates your values:

```
$op .= trim($tmp[0],"'\"")." ";
```

Try to replace this by just an assignment

```
$op = trim($tmp[0],"'\"")." ";
```

[Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Your answer works correct.  My final question. I need to check if certain name is in the array with the **names** result something like `$name_search ='Ann';
$result_names = array("Ann","Mike");
if (!in_array($name_search, $result_names)) { 
echo "echo Name not Found";

}else{
echo "echo Name Found ";

}`   I have tried this but it keep saying Name not found  `$result_names = $names;
$name_search ='Ann';
if (!in_array($name_search, $result_names)) { 
echo "Name not Found";

}else{
echo "Name Found ";

}`

Answer (score 2):

```php
$str = 'Ann is good, "Mike loves cooking", "O\'Reilly" haz bookz';

$sentences = explode(',', $str);

$names = array_map(
    fn($s) => trim(
        explode(
            ' ',
            ltrim($s)
        )[0],
        "'\""
    ),
    $sentences
);

print_r($names);
```

Later explanation:

Answering the initial question, "How to properly Get first word of every sentence..." here is my vision of the solution. Which may have flaws or be completely wrong, in this case please correct me.

The solution is based on the following rules learned from the original code:

1. sentences are split by a comma inside a source string, words are split by spaces;
2. commas appearing inside quotes or apostrophes are still considered sentence dividers, so no need to parse the source more thoroughly;
3. quotes and apostrophes, surrounding the word should be removed, if appear inside the word, they are kept (example: `D'Artagnan`).

With this in mind the following algorithm seems to be "proper" (ignoring the emotional bias of "proper"):

1. split the source string by comma into `$sentences` array (line 3);
2. since there may be situations when commas are surrounded by spaces, and to avoid empty words in this case, we need to left-trim every sentence before splitting it into words (line 9);
3. split every sentence by space into an array of words (line 7) and only keep the first word (line 10);
4. remove quotes and apostrophes surrounding the first word (line 6);
5. store the list of words in `$names` variable (line 12).

Since no php version specified, we consider the use of currently supported php version.

If you need more information, please refer to php manual for the following constructs:

- [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) — *a more concise syntax for anonymous functions*
- [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map) — *applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays*

Comment: This is also an approach that would work. However you supplied no other information whatsoever. As you can see in my answer, I pointed out **what** was wrong with his code so he could learn from his mistakes. Additionally you could provide another method but with this answer only, without explanation, the OP is not really helped.

Comment: Thank you @Wimanicesir for this lesson. But I am here to help, not to teach. If person is willing to learn, she'll learn from the code.

Comment: Well, as I said in previous comment. You are not really helping here.

Comment: Adding to @Wimanicesir: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) | [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Wimanicesir and @jasie: sorry if breaking some rules while accommodating myself on this platform. Used it for years to find answers but only decided to start contributing now. From my personal experience (which is subjective, of course) explaining the code in details is like explaining jokes. I love [so] not because of the explanations, but because of different approaches that people tend to demonstrate giving different answers to initial question. Anyway the first comment from ADyson was enough to correct the user problem and the follow-up, so I wanted to show how to resolve it differently

Comment: @StasTrefilov, Your explanation makes your answer way better! Anyhow I want to note 2 things: 1. Referring to the line in your text is a bit unpractical, (next time) consider to add comments in your code itself ;) 2. Explaining a joke actually would be logic on a forum where people don't get the joke, just telling the joke another way may not help him understand better. Your analogy is actually an argument to do explanation :)